# Django session translation setting is sticky for all languages, except Chinese?

Tags: python, django, gettext, django-i18n

I have a really weird problem I've never seen before. I'm using Django 1.10.

I have several dictionary files:

```
/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
/locale/zh/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
```

The application strings are written in English. The dictionary files are complete, and compiled to `mo` files.

I store each user's language preference in the `language` field of the `UserProfile`. When updating their profile, I apply the language translation to the session.

```
# 'up' is a UserProfile object pertaining to the user
up.update(language=form.cleaned_data['language'])
translation.activate(up.language)
self.request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = up.language
return super(self, UpdateUserProfile).form_valid(form)
```

This works fine for French and German. The `return super` renders the form template in French/German, and then I can navigate to other pages and see French/German text.

It doesn't work for Chinese (language code 'zh'). The `return super` page renders the form template in Chinese (and I've verified the language setting in the shell after saving), but then unlike French and German, all other pages revert to English when I navigate away.

I've restarted the dev server just in case it was due to old settings. I've tried it out on a clean pull of that branch on a fresh, isolated dev VM. I have the same problem for Chinese in both scenarios. What could cause this error?

#### Edit - additional information:

From settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
LOCALE_PATHS = [ 
    BASE_DIR + '/locale/',
]
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

As mentioned, on POST for the UpdateLanguage `FormView` the `request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY]` code is set to `zh`, and the page displays in Chinese. On a GET request to the same view the page displays in English (however examining `request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY]` shows it is set to `zh` despite displaying English text).

I'm not using language prefixes in the urls.

Comment: What language settings did you set in your Django settings? Are you using the language prefix in your urls? Did you trace the value stored in the session? On subsequent requests, is the value of `request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY]` a correct value? Edit the question with this information.

Comment: @Louis Thanks for the suggestions, I've updated the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've correctly [inferred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41891042/1906307) that `zh` is not a code that is part of the default `LANGUAGES` setting and thus is  not working right.

The reason you got Chinese when producing the first page is that you make a call equivalent to `translation.activate("zh")`. This call does not check `LANGUAGES`. It blindly activates the translation for the language `zh`. If the files are there for "zh" there's no problem. You could do `translation.activate("turnip")` and Django would be fine with it so long as the files for the language "turnip" exist..

The reason it did not work on subsequent page requests is that the [locale middleware](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/locale.py) *does* check against `LANGUAGES` and rejects values that are not listed there: it switches back to the default language you configured for your site.

Here is code that illustrates the two cases:

```
import os

import django
from django.utils.translation import trans_real as translation, LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY
from django.middleware.locale import LocaleMiddleware

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "btw.settings")
django.setup()

#
# Calling translation.activate directly.
#
translation.activate("zh")
value = translation._active.value
print "translation:", value.language()

#
# Middleware processing
#
class FakeRequest(object):

    path_info = ""
    session = {}
    COOKIES = {}
    META = {}

middleware = LocaleMiddleware()

for lang in ("fr", "zh", "zh-hans"):
    print "Trying:", lang
    request = FakeRequest()
    request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = lang

    middleware.process_request(request)
    print request.LANGUAGE_CODE
```

You'll see in the 2nd part using the middleware that when you select "zh" as the language, `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` is set to the default language for your site instead of being "zh" or some variant of it. On my system, the output is:

```
translation: zh
Trying: fr
fr
Trying: zh
en-us
Trying: zh-hans
zh-hans
```

Comment: Does this mean that I should `makemessages -l zh-hans` with the actual language code? At the moment, I made my chinese dictionary file using `-l zh` and setting the `LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY` to the non-matching `zh-hans` is picking it up - why would this be?

Comment: That's because the logic is such that it looks for a set of files for the whole language code, and if it does not find one it truncates at the dash and tries again. So if it cannot find files for `zh-hans` but files for `zh` exist, it will use the latter. You can check this by calling the `check_for_language` function in the `trans_real` package. If you call it with an obviously ridiculous value like `en-potato`, it will report that the language exists because it has `en`. You can also see the path if you call `gettext.find` directly. (See the code of `check_for_language` for an example.)

Comment: At the end of the day, I would want different files for `zh-hans` and `zh-hant`. This is not a Django thing but what the two options represent: `zh-hans` is simplified Chinese. `zh-hant` is traditional Chinese. The difference is that in simplified, some of the characters are different. People in different regions use either traditional or simplified. You might want to search the internet about how people raised on traditional feel about simplified Chinese and decide on that basis whether you should support both, or only simplified.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, all the debugging output from django debug toolbar indicated that I was doing the right thing, so I looked at the source of [global_settings.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/global_settings.py)

`zh` isn't actually a valid language code. You have to choose between simplified `zh-hans` and traditional `zh-hant`, and the fact that the page weirdly rendered in Chinese for the HttpResponse after the session language was set made me thing the problem was with the session, not the settings.